# Looking for a simple way to add check boxs into list columns (wxPython)

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Firstly, I was wondering, is there a native style which can be added into wx.ListCtrl so that it could function like this simple UI (mostly the checkbox part in the first column):

[image: How do I do this in wxPython]

If not, well I couldn't find any in its style list, then what's the most elegant way to do it (put checkboxes in the first column, and the first one serves as Check All/Uncheck All)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15730239/2683116), describing application of `CheckListCtrlMixin`. However, it does not have the `CheckBox` in the column header. For binding use the callback as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594981/what-event-is-emitted-by-wxpython-when-an-item-in-a-checklistctrlmixin-is-checke). You can find an example for it in the wxPython demo.

You can also find `UltimateListCtrl` in the demo, which should offer the ckeckbox in the column header (I never have used it).